# Sql query count duplicates while grouping them

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find total price grouped by per quarter and product(price * quantity).

Sample data

```
 Products Quarter Quantity Price
  prod1    Q1        2       1.5
  prod1    Q2        3       2.5
  prod2    Q1        4       3
  prod3    Q2        5       3.5
```

Expected Output

```
Product Quarter  Quantity Price
 prod1    Q1        2       3
 prod1    Q2        3       7.5
 prod2    Q1        4       12
 prod3    Q2        5       17.5
```

I have run the query below:

```
SELECT Quarter,Products,(Price * Quantity) as tot_price FROM table-name GROUP by Products,Quarter;
```

But the output is incorrect.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and include the following: 1) sample input data as _text_, not an image and 2) the expected output, also as text, not as an image.

Comment: Could this question be any more confusing? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: *Also to sum qty and cost separately per quarter* what is qty and price? You did not include them in your sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas qty and price are shown in the sample data

Comment: They were not there when I posted the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45778274/8

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I did nor downvote. Why should I? I answered and you accepted.

Comment: @forpas yes your right, i didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your expected results you don't need any grouping, only a calculated column:

```
select
  product,
  quarter,
  quantity,
  (quantity * price) totalprice
from tablename
```

**Edit**:
If you need grouping per product and quarter:

```
select
  product,
  quarter,
  sum(quantity) total quantity,
  sum(quantity * price) totalprice
from tablename 
group by product, quarter
```

Comment: I need grouping per Quarter and Product, e.g group all prod1 - Q1 find tot price, prod2 - Q1 find tot price. It's just sample, i have many prod1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Giving you few hints:
- sum: this aggregation function can be used for summation 
- count: this is used for counting

In order to sum up qty, cost per quarter,
Query can be:

select Quarter, sum(qty), sum(cost) from tableName group by Quarter

To get stats per product and quarter, 
Query can be:

select Products, Quarter, sum(qty), sum(cost) from tableName group by Products, Quarter

Comment: Yes but i must divide the result from summation with the quarter frequency for each product.e.g (sum(qty) / counter)